# Looking for NEC code article number for separate ground and neutral in subpanel being fed from service entrance

Tags: electrical-panel

Need code article justifying why I can isolate grounded and grounding conductor in subpanel. Subpanel is fed from a 200-amp service.

Comment: It's not "Why you can" it's "Why you **must**"

Comment: @ecnerwal, I was thinking the same thing but did not want to get long winded.

Answer (score 7):

NEC 250.32.B.1. there is a pretty picture in exhibit 250.20 that actually shows exactly what you are asking.